# unpredictable floating point errors from matrix decomposition

Tags: c, opengl, math, matrix, floating-point

I'm trying to decompose perspective matrix's near and far distances by using this formula:

```
near = m32 / (m22 - 1);
far  = m32 / (m22 + 1);
```

Here the perspective matrix test parameters:

```
  aspect   = 0.782f;
  fovy     = glm_rad(49.984f);
  nearDist = 0.1550385f;
  farDist  = 6000.340975f;

  glm_perspective(fovy, aspect, nearDist, farDist, proj);
```

Here what I'm doing to get near and far values (proj is column-major matrix):

```
far  = proj[3][2] / (proj[2][2] + 1.0f);
near = proj[3][2] / (proj[2][2] - 1.0f)
```

Results:

```
near = 0.155039 
far  = 5993.506348
```

Near seems acceptable but far is not :/ If I use small value for `far` then I get more accurate results (right values are decomposed values):

```
farDist = 600.340975 (near, far): 0.155039 600.319885 
farDist = 60.340975f (near, far): 0.155039 60.340946
```

Is there something wrong with math? What options do I have (without using double to store matrix)?

You can see perspective matrix formula here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml

```
m22 = (near + far) / (near - far)
m32 = 2 * near * far / (near - far)
```

and implementation (line number may change by time): https://github.com/recp/cglm/blob/master/include/cglm/cam.h#L211

Comment: Perhaps for select code, use `double` math --> `m32 / (m22 + 1.0);`

Comment: I guess you mean: `((double)proj[3][2]) / ((double)proj[2][2] + 1.0)` output is same: `5993.506348` it must be least 6000 :( Even I tried to compute m22 and m32 with `double` result is same until I make nearDist and farDist `double` too (everything is double), after that result is `6000.340820` not so bad but not so good for `double`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the larger the `far/near` ratio gets, it requires more significant digits to extract `far` from the perspective matrix.

When the `far/near` ratio increases, `m22 = (near+far)/(near-far)` gets closer to 1.

For example, using `double` with `near=0.155`, and `far=6,000`, we get `m22 = 1.0000516680014233`. When this is stored as `float`, it is truncated to `1.0000516`.

The important part of the result is the fraction. Even if all other opeartions are done with perfect accuracy, at this point you are already left with just 3 significant digits. This is very similar to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Essentially, you lose a significant digit every time `far/near` is multiplied by 10. When `far` is `6,000,000`, the value of `m22` would be truncated to `1.0` when stored as `float`, losing *all* information.

I tried to demonstrate it in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/sterin/libraries/perspective/html/precision.ipynb).

But the real problem is not only that is is impossible to extract `far` without losing precision, but that the perspecive matrix itself is not accurate.

If you take a vector at `z=6,000`, apply the perspective matrix, you will not get z=1.0. Instead, applying the perspective matrix to a vector with the incorrect value of `far`, `z=5993.506348` will give you `z=1.0`. The matrix itself is already wrong, so no method of extracting `far` can help.

TL;DR: If you want to extract `near` and `far` from a perspective matrix with reasonable accuracy, you have to use `double`.

Edited: added an explanation for the real problem, the original answer regarding catastrophic cancellation is just a second order effect.

Comment: I will investigate catastrophic cancellation thanks for pointing out

Comment: great answer! I must warn users about this. There will be double version too but probably most users including me will use single precision float (performance + memory usage + cpu cache ...). And I must select a small far distance for unit testing.

Comment: in the future maybe `glm_perspective` could try to fix/minimize these errors by changing given near and far parameters (inside func) or it can be alternative func like   `glm_perspective_safe`. I don't know if can do it but added to my TODOs.

Answer (score 2):

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. The projection matrix transforms from view space to the clip space. Clip space coordinates are [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) in the range (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates.

[image]

Because of that, a point with a Z-cooridnate of -1 is on the near plane and a point with a Z-cooridnate of 1 is on the far plane (in normalized device space).

To calculate the distance to the near plane and the far plane, you have to transform a point on the near plane and a point on the far plane by the **inverse** projection matrix. Then you have to do a perspective divide. The distance to the near or far plane is the inverted Z-coordinate of the result:

```
mat4 proj;

mat4 invProj = inverse( proj );

vec4 ndcNear(0, 0, -1, 1);
vec4 ndcFar(0, 0, 1, 1);

vec4 ptNear = invProj * ndcNear;
vec4 ptFar  = invProj * ndcFar;

near = - ptNear[2] / ptNear[3];
far  = - ptFar[2]  / ptFar[3];
```

Comment: maybe this is alternative way but it is more costly then this: m32 / (m22 + 1), it would be better to get far distance from single division

Comment: Also did you mean invViewProj instead of invProj? Results: 0.155039 5974.791992 it seems worse than just divison

Comment: @recp No, I mean the inverse of the projection matrix. And it gives the exact result for perspective and orthographic projection.

Comment: maybe it is all about floating point errors I don't know but I hope there is a way to avoid or fix it without using double precision

Comment: This method suffers from the same numerical accuracy problems. (it is better, though, because it does not depend on the exact formulation of the perspective matrix).